# Stored password in Safari Versus Firefox

Tags: safari, password, firefox

Is there a way to retrieve password stored in Safari as it is possible to do it in Firefox ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Safari stores its passwords in the OSX Keychain.  Open `/Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app`, select the "Login" keychain (this should be default) and select "Passwords" under "Category".  Doubleclick an entry and check "Show password"; you'll be asked for your login keychain password (this is usually the same as your account password).

(For a while I was using an add-on for Firefox that used the Keychain, but it was highly broken.)

Comment: It is also possible to copy the password to then paste it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is the Safari extension LastPass [see lastpass.com].  This is also a Firefox addon.  You could migrate your passwords and secure notes to LastPass and they would be available on any browser and on any machine.  This extension was scrutinized by a security expert on the podcast "Security Now" episode #256 [show transcript at http://www.grc.com/sn/sn-256.htm]

Answer (score 0):

Actually they are available more conveniently in Safari itself:

Preferences... -> Passwords